# Как изменить цвет значков в statusbar

Tags: android

У меня белый statusbar, при этом значки в нём тоже белые и сливаются, как поменять цвет именно значков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден, `windowLightStatusBar`

Answer (score 0):

Там можно посмотреть src\main\res\values\ colors